# Output error messages from abort on custom error pages in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I've created a custom error template for 401 and 404 errors by [following the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#http-exceptions). They display fine with a fixed error message, but when triggering the error with `abort()` you can pass in an error message as the second argument. What variable do I need to output to show the message passed through abort? Nothing in the documentation tells you how to output that message on the page and any search for error messages either shows info about the validation function or goes on about logging and triggering errors, but not how to output them on the page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your view there will be an `$exception` variable, that is an instance of `HttpException`.

You can use `$exception->getMessage()` method to get your message.